# Почему eslint выдаёт предупреждение что переменная не используется?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Здравствуйте имеется сборка webpack c eslint, файл javascript содержит следующий код:

```
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slider__img-gallary');
const auto = true;
const intervalTime = 8000;
let slideInterval;

const nextSlide = () => {
    const current = document.querySelector('.slider__img-gallary_current-slide');
    current.classList.remove('slider__img-gallary_current-slide');
    if (current.nextElementSibling) {
        current.nextElementSibling.classList.add('slider__img-gallary_current-slide');
    } else {
        slides[0].classList.add('slider__img-gallary_current-slide');
    }
    setTimeout(() => current.classList.remove('slider__img-gallary_current-slide'));
}

if(auto) {
    slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, intervalTime);
}
```

При запуске, eslint выдаёт предупреждение 'slideInterval' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars, помогите пожалуйста в чём может быть проблема, ведь переменная slideInterval используется.
Фал конфигурации .eslintrc:

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "rules": {
        "no-unused-vars": "warn"
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Переменной `slideInterval` присваивается значение, но это значение *из* переменной нигде не используется. Значит эта переменная вообще не нужна.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Проблему решил.